# How do I reward an instructive answer over a good answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1189222/cd-rom-subchannel-is-different-when-dumping-the-same-disc) on superuser that led to two answers.
[Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)'s seems to be a good practical answer to my question.
However [dirkt](https://superuser.com/users/327880/dirkt)'s answer gave me a lot of context, interesting links and made me learn quite a lot.

So here is my question how can I reward [dirkt](https://superuser.com/users/327880/dirkt) for the time he took to explain all those things while I will probably award the answer and bounty to [Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)?

Comment: Nothing stops you from accepting one answer and manually awarding the bounty to a different one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always [offer another bounty](https://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the question after the existing bounty is finished.

In this case the minimum rep you can award would be doubled up to 100, so you should be sure that you believe the answer merits it, but I have seen bounties used on several occasions to reward exemplary answers.

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

In fact as you go through the process to start a bounty one of the options is

> **Reward existing answer**
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty

Comment: Sounds like the good thing to do. I will still have to decide which answer deserves a bigger bounty but I think I will do this. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: They are both excellent answers and deserving a bonus for their time and effort. If you would like to award the bounty to one, then I would be willing to give a bounty for the other. I believe the double minimum rep spend only applies to bounties posted by the same user.